# no possibility to log in / register after transferring files

Tags: magento-2.1

I moved and run all my online site files and database to localhost.

everything works fine but when I try to login or create new account (front-page) nothing reacts.

In the first place entered correct data then I click login - then the page refreshes and deletes only all data from the form.

the same problem is when trying to set up a new customer account on the fron page, I checked in the administration panel and there is no any new account.

when I add product to the basket, a message is displayed after a while

"You do not have any products in your cart. Click here to continue shopping."

everything works fine on the online site so I do not know why I get this error on localhost.

Comment: In `Stores > Configuration > General > Web` check if your cookie domain and cookie path are not pointing to old domains. If not then make sure your settings for session (in `app/etc/env.php`) are correct and path is writable.

Comment: in WEB everything is correctly set up. localhost/magento

or any other advice?